ADF test output in R
I Run ADF test with R for 3 different models include,

No deterministic terms,
with constant and
constant and trend based on the below code.

However, I am unsure about which corresponding p-value (I mean z.lag.1, z.diff.lag.1 or z.diff.lag.2) to report for each model (Model 1, 2, and 3) based on the output of my code as shown below after the code.
adf_no_det <- ur.df(residuals, type = "none", lags = 2)
print("P-Value:")
# Constant term
adf_const <- ur.df(residuals, type = "drift", lags = 2)
#  constant and trend
adf_const_trend <- ur.df(residuals, type = "trend", lags = 2)

# Output the test results
summary(adf_no_det)
summary(adf_const)
summary(adf_const_trend)
 #Output
summary(adf_no_det)

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 
Test regression none 
Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.28258 -0.01857  0.00217  0.02153  0.36875 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
z.lag.1     -0.012833   0.003297  -3.892 0.000103 ***
z.diff.lag1  0.301283   0.023305  12.928  < 2e-16 ***
z.diff.lag2 -0.073263   0.023399  -3.131 0.001770 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03876 on 1817 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08934,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.08784 
F-statistic: 59.42 on 3 and 1817 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
Value of test-statistic is: -3.8921 
Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.58 -1.95 -1.62

> summary(adf_const)
############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression drift 
Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + z.diff.lag)
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.28243 -0.01842  0.00233  0.02168  0.36890 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.0001580  0.0009088  -0.174 0.862039    
z.lag.1     -0.0128355  0.0032981  -3.892 0.000103 ***
z.diff.lag1  0.3012700  0.0233110  12.924  < 2e-16 ***
z.diff.lag2 -0.0732705  0.0234056  -3.130 0.001773 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03877 on 1816 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08934,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.08784 
F-statistic: 59.39 on 3 and 1816 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
Value of test-statistic is: -3.8917 7.5851 
Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.43 -2.86 -2.57
phi1  6.43  4.59  3.78

> summary(adf_const_trend)
############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 
Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.28240 -0.01840  0.00238  0.02166  0.36893 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.759e-04  1.822e-03  -0.151 0.879648    
z.lag.1     -1.283e-02  3.299e-03  -3.889 0.000104 ***
tt           1.293e-07  1.730e-06   0.075 0.940459    
z.diff.lag1  3.013e-01  2.332e-02  12.920  < 2e-16 ***
z.diff.lag2 -7.328e-02  2.341e-02  -3.130 0.001776 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03878 on 1815 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08934,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.08734 
F-statistic: 44.52 on 4 and 1815 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Value of test-statistic is: -3.8894 5.0559 7.5715 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -3.96 -3.41 -3.12
phi2  6.09  4.68  4.03
phi3  8.27  6.25  5.34


